# sending file as a link instead of an attachment in the mail

Tags: java, hyperlink, jakarta-mail

Is it possible to send the file as a link instead of attaching the file in the email. I am sending an email using Java . Now, i have a requirement thatI don't want to send the file as an attachement instead I need to send it as a link.

Link will something be like `abc.com\report\excel\"fileName"`, in which `abc.com` is the host/ machine name, and rest is the path location.

Thanks.

Comment: In my opinion you can try to send html based email, where you define html links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mail format does't allow meta-attachments (i.e. by reference, not by instance).
Your only option is sending HTML email with HTML link to the file (and of course it should be accessible via internet).